# How to send one of the json parameter of a request body through url and rest through body of postman for @Postmapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I have a class:

```java
public class SubMdl {

    private Integer Id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String mssd;
        
    private String name;
    
    private String location;

//constructor,getters,setters

}
```

While doing @Postmapping can we send mssd in the url and rest of the data in the json body in the postman combined?

If possible then what will be written in controller class as @RequestBody in the controller will expect whole data and definitely considering @NotEmpty.

Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 1):

You can send `mssd` as `PathVariable` or `RequestParam` and rest of the parameter as `ReqeustBody` as below.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public String samplePost(@PathVariable("mssd") String mssd, @RequestBody SubMdlChild payload){
       return <your-service-call>;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** In the `RequestBody`, I have taken a sample class name `SubMdlChild` which will not contain the `mssd` as per your requirement.

Comment: Since the OP asked for the request body containing all data but `mssd`, I think using another class which contains all fields except `mssd` will be more suitable.

Comment: Are there any other useful ways available?